# What's Faster/More Efficient For Grabbing First 10 Elements In Array

Tags: php

I need the key, value, and index of the first 10 elements of my sorted **associative** array.

```
$top10pts = array_slice($toppoints, 0, 10);
foreach ($top10pts as $key => $val) {
    echo "<tr><td>".(array_search($key, array_keys($top10pts))+1)."</td><td>".htmlentities($key)."</td><td>".$val."</td></tr>";
}
```

or

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $val = array_slice($toppoints, $i, 1);
    echo "<tr><td>".($i+1)."</td><td>".htmlentities(key($val))."</td><td>".$val[key($val)]."</td></tr>";
}
```

or another method?

Being new to PHP, both methods seem stupid and superfluous.

Comment: I think array_slice is good.

Comment: Akam, again! This was what I was about to write - `array_slice($array, 0, 10)` or `array_slice($array, 10)` :-)

Comment: You have two options there, benchmark them and find out!

Comment: if the speed difference matters here, you have much bigger issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best method that came to my mind.

```
$top10pts = array_slice($toppoints, 0, 10);
$i = 1;
foreach ($top10pts as $key => $val)
    echo "<tr><td>".($i++)."</td><td>".htmlentities($key)."</td><td>".$val."</td></tr>";
```

Notice that, for more than 10 items, this method works better because it has no conditions in the loop. In interpreters such as *php*, it's usually better to use internal functions rather than doing the things yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to ernie's answer but you dont need array slice at all

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($top10pts as $key => $val) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$index++."</td><td>".htmlentities($key)."</td><td>".$val."</td></tr>";
    if($index >=10) break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you sorted already, a foreach will iterate in order, so I'd use a modification of your first, getting rid of the `array_search`: . . .

```
$index = 0;
$top10pts = array_slice($toppoints, 0, 10);
foreach ($top10pts as $key => $val) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$index."</td><td>".htmlentities($key)."</td><td>".$val."</td></tr>";
    $index++;
}
```